# Windows performance monitor new instances

Tags: performance, performance-monitoring, perfmon

I am trying to configure performance monitor on 2003/2008R1&R2 to capture new instances of the counters without any luck. 
For example if I select counter **Process\%Processor time** (to monitor processor time per any instances of the process) everything works fine until I open or close any application. 
If in the meanwhile new application is open it will not be included in the monitoring processor, and old application instance will display zero for % processor time.

The problem is performance monitor is not refreshing instances of the new applications/users/new terminal session/ or any other metrics that changes instances in the meanwhile.

The solution is to stop/start log file, but I don't want to do that every sec and the logging will be split into two files. Anybody knows how do I accomplish to add all new instances?

Any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that you are logging in one of the "Text File" formats. These cannot be used if you want dynamic activity (new processes, etc.) to be captured.

Instead, use the "Binary File" format to capture your data. This will allow perfmon to capture any dynamic activity for the counters that you assign.

Once you collection is completed, if you wish to open the log in Excel/etc., you can use the `relog.exe` program (included with Windows...) to convert the binary file into a text file. The syntax is:

```
relog.exe logfile.blg -f csv -o logfile.csv
```

Comment: Stumbled upon this answer because this is really quite challenging and confusing task to do. The problem is that you CANNOT view the binary report file in a perfmon window, because it shows only ProcessorTime\_Total even when you have set your collector with All Instances. It is really interesting that using this utility relog on a resulting BLG makes a CSV file which contains columns for all processes running during the collector runtime INCLUDING the new processes launched. But why can't I view this data as a graph in perfmon even now after 8 years and several new OSes is a mystery to me.